# Setting property of child control from within constructor of parent control

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a parent wpf window P which uses a "user control" C as shown below:

```
<widgets:NonBlockingLoadingDecorator Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  >    
    <local:MyUserControl x:Name="objUserControl" MouseDoubleClick="OnItemDoubleClick"/>
</widgets:NonBlockingLoadingDecorator>
```

I've a property in child control as follows:

```
public log4net.ILog Log { get; set; }
```

I need to be able to set this property from the constructor of the parent window so that I can read the property in the child control as follows...

User control:

```
public C()
    {

      InitializeComponent();
      this.Log.Debug("My user control...");
     }
```

Parent:

```
public P()
    {
            C.Log = myLog;
            InitializeComponent();
    }
```

But this does not seem to work.How do I achieve this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `x:Name` XAML attribute creates a member variable with that name, and type `MyUserControl`, in your parent class.

You can access that member after calling `InitializeComponent()`:

```
public P()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    objUserControl.Log = myLog;
}
```

In the UserControl, you should avoid accessing the Log property before it is assigned a value, e.g. like

```
if (Log != null)
{
    Log.Debug("...");
}
```

Or shorter:

```
Log?.Debug("...");
```

---

Alternatively you may also make the property static, so you can access it before a UserControl instance is created, like

```
public static log4net.ILog Log { get; set; }
```

Now you could actually write

```
public P()
{
    C.Log = myLog;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Note however that all instances of `C` would now use the same Log object.

Comment: The constructor of the UserControl will still return before the property is set, so by the time the Log property is accessed in the UserControl's constructor it will still be null.

Comment: @Jimmy That's why you should avoid to log before a property value was assigned. See the alternative mentioned in the answer. As another alternative, you may pass an ILog as constructor parameter, but that doesn't seem to be worth the effort. Note that you would somehow have to get access to the log object in XAML then.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `InitializeComponent()` in the constuctor of the window will realize the element tree that you have defined in the XAML markup and an instance of the `UserControl` will be created. *After* this you can set any property of the `UserControl` using the backing field:

```
objUserControl.Log = myLog;
```

Note that by the time the constructor of the `UserControl` gets invoked, the `Log` property has not yet been set though. You can't set a property before you have created an instance of the class.

This means that you can't log something in the `UserControl`'s constructor, unless you set the `Log` property to some default logger in the `UserControl` class itself, or make the property `static` and set it *before* you call `InitializeComponent()`.